# Вывести значения из JSON в RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, recyclerview, kotlin

Исходный JSON:

```
{"row":[{"name":"Maria","address":"Paris"},{"name":"John","address":"USA"}]}
```

Нужно разобрать и вывести в RecyclerView. Нужно вывести все объекты, не понимаю как реализовать. Могу только обратиться к одному элементу и вывести его, или задать с помощью "users.add(User("Name", "Address"))" сколько нужно полей, но мне надо из JSON. Нужно решение.
Пример:

---

Maria
Paris

---

John
USA

```
val builder = GsonBuilder()
        val gson: Gson = builder.create()
        val deSerial = gson.fromJson(otherVar, Row::class.java)
        do {
            users.add(User("Name", "Address"))
        }while (users.size<2)
```

---

```
data class Row(val row:List<User>)
data class User(val name: String, val address: String)
```

Comment: JSON возвращает какая-то API? Если да, как ходите на API?

Comment: @Eugene Zaychenko,  JSON возвращает сайт http://myjson.com/. Получаю http-библиотекой fuel. Проблема в выводе данных. Данные приходят 100%.

Comment: Не знаю как это правильно на kotlin, что-то вроде: `users.addAll(deSerial.row)`

Comment: судя по всему вам больше подойтет Retrofit2, пример маппинга в RecyclerView можно посмотреть здесь https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: В `otherVar` у вас исходный JSON, что в начале вопроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этот код на 100% рабочий, не понимаю чего вы еще колдуете?

```
val builder = GsonBuilder()
val gson: Gson = builder.create()
val deSerial = gson.fromJson(otherVar, Row::class.java)
```

Если `otherVar` содержит JSON строку, что в начале вопроса, но на выходе в `deSerial` получите объект со списком пользователей.

Дальше делайте со списком что хотите.

```
deSerial.row.forEach { it.address + it.name }
```